# Visual Studio Code HTML and CSS linter validator customization

Tags: html, css, validation, visual-studio-code, lint

Is there an easy way to customize the behavior of Visual Studio Code HTML / CSS linter validation rules?

I would like to have possibility to put data placeholders to the code to styles, attributes, text nodes such as:

```html
<style type="text/css">

   .testa {
      color: white;
      background-color: navy;
      transition: color 1s, background-color 1s;
   }

</style>

<template>

   <div class="testa" onclick="{{testClick}}" style="background-color: {{backgroundColor}}; color: {{color}}" >
      {{firstName}} {{lastName}} {{firstName} {{lastName}}
   </div>

   <div style="{{style}}">
      {{firstName}} {{lastName}}
   </div>

</template>
```

It does not need to be a {{...}} placeholder. It can be whatever else, such as ${}, but I would like Visual Studio Code to not report this as errors while there is still a possibility to have intellisense and validation enabled.

Comment: Hey, which programming language are you using? For me, it's looking similar to VUE and it has the same possibilty to use placeholders. Beside of that, you could use a plugin like ESLint to have more power about your configuration.

Comment: Its my custom templating. And I am bit lazy to write complete language service for HTML/CSS. Moreover, it would be great to use something standard, but customizable, ESLint is great, but its for TypeScript/ECMAScript so not much useful in this case. I would like to have HTML extension set for templates.

Comment: It's maybe a bit hacky: Couldn't you set the rules for HTML-Files to another Language Mode like Blade or Vue in the bottom right corner? So VS-Code treats it as a another File-Extension with the same rules?

Comment: Let me try this, but it would be better to have some more standard solution

Comment: Have you looked into using Prettier? That's your best bet I think since it has tons of customization options and I can usually find a rule someones made for the thing I wanna validate.

Answer (score 0):

Install a [Twig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twig_(template_engine)) plugin for Visual Studio Code. ([Here's first one I found](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mblode.twig-language).)

[Then tell Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers) to associate `.html` files with Twig under the `file.associations` setting. `{{firstName}}` is valid Twig code, so Visual Studio Code will think it's OK.